# J-Query Works Perfectly on Desktop Stops Work online

Tags: jquery, html

I have this simple JQ Cart that i want to add to my website, however it never worked, so i made a sepreat html file with cart and tested it locally and it worked perfectly. I uploaded all files as is to my websever via ftp however it doesnt work,

I spent hours searching for possible error but no luck, can anyone kindly take a quick look and tell me what could it be ??

below is the index

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <!-- CSS for this product-->
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="lib/dc.core.1.1.0.min.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="lib/dc.cart.css" />
        <!-- CSS for this example only-->
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="common/sample.common.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="common/sample.product.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="common/prettify.css" />
        <!-- Javascript for this product-->
        <script src="lib/dc.core.1.1.0.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="lib/dc.cart.free.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="lib/dc.cart.lang.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <!-- CSS for this example only-->
        <script src="common/prettify.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(function() {

                // Create a new AJAXPaypalCart Object
                var cart = $('#cart').DCAJAXPaypalCart({
                    width: 600,
                    autoOpenWhenAdd: true,
                    openNewCheckOutWindow: true,
                    //themeColor:'#333',
                    //themeDarkColor:'#FFF',
                    header: 'AJAX Cart Demo',
                    footer: 'We accpet paypal, visa and master card. (This is a customizable footer)',
                    paypalOptions: {
                        business: 'tsangwl@digicrafts.com.hk',
                        page_style: 'digicrafts'
                    }
                });

                // Add the button
                cart.addBuyButton("#macbook", {
                    name: 'MacBook', // Item name appear on the cart
                    thumbnail: 'med/macbook.jpg', // Thumbnail path of the item (Optional)
                    price: '999', // Cost of the item
                    shipping: 20 // Shipping cost for the item (Optional)
                });
                cart.addBuyButton("#macbookair", {
                    name: 'MacBook Air',
                    thumbnail: 'med/macbook.jpg',
                    price: '999',
                    shipping: 20
                });
                cart.addBuyButton("#macbookpro", {
                    name: 'MacBook Pro',
                    thumbnail: 'med/macbookpro.jpg',
                    price: '1199',
                    shipping: 0
                });
                cart.addBuyButton("#imac", {
                    name: 'iMac',
                    thumbnail: 'med/macbook.jpg',
                    price: '1199',
                    shipping: 0
                });
                cart.addBuyButton("#macmini", {
                    name: 'Mac Mini',
                    thumbnail: 'med/macbookpro.jpg',
                    price: '699',
                    shipping: 20
                });
                cart.addBuyButton("#macpro", {
                    name: 'Mac pro',
                    thumbnail: 'med/macpro.jpg',
                    price: '2499'
                });
                cart.addBuyButton("#macosx", {
                    name: 'Mac OS X',
                    thumbnail: 'med/macosx.jpg',
                    price: '99',
                    allowMultiple: false
                });

                // For code highlight
                prettyPrint();

            });
        </script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="pageWrapper">
            <!--End: Common Header -->
            <div class="product_list">
                <div class="product_list_header">Demo Store
                    <div class="sub"></div>
                    <div id="cart">Cart</div>
                </div>
                <div id="product_list" class="product_list_content">
                    <div class="product">
                        <div class="thumbnail">
                            <img src="med/macbook.jpg" />
                        </div>
                        <div class="caption">
                            <div class="text">
                                <div class="main">MacBook</div>
                                <div class="sub">(shipping $20)</div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="button" id="macbook">buy $999</div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="product">
                        <div class="thumbnail">
                            <img src="med/macbookair.jpg" />
                        </div>
                        <div class="caption">
                            <div class="text">
                                <div class="main">MacBook Air</div>
                                <div class="sub">(shipping $20)</div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="button" id="macbookair">buy $999</div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="product">
                        <div class="thumbnail">
                            <img src="med/macbookpro.jpg" />
                        </div>
                        <div class="caption">
                            <div class="text">
                                <div class="main">MacBook Pro</div>
                                <div class="sub">(free shipping)</div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="button" id="macbookpro">buy $1199</div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="product">
                        <div class="thumbnail">
                            <img src="med/macosx.jpg" />
                        </div>
                        <div class="caption">
                            <div class="text">
                                <div class="main">Mac OS X</div>
                                <div class="sub">(Purchase once|Download)</div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="button" id="macosx">buy $99</div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="product">
                        <div class="thumbnail">
                            <img src="med/imac.jpg" />
                        </div>
                        <div class="caption">
                            <div class="text">
                                <div class="main">iMac</div>
                                <div class="sub">(free shipping)</div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="button" id="imac">buy $1199</div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="product">
                        <div class="thumbnail">
                            <img src="med/macmini.jpg" />
                        </div>
                        <div class="caption">
                            <div class="text">
                                <div class="main">Mac Mini</div>
                                <div class="sub">(shipping $20)</div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="button" id="macmini">buy $699</div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="product">
                        <div class="thumbnail">
                            <img src="med/macpro.jpg" />
                        </div>
                        <div class="caption">
                            <div class="text">
                                <div class="main">Mac Pro</div>
                                <div class="sub">(free shipping)</div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="button" id="macpro">buy $2499</div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: What error(s) are you getting in the debugger console of your browser?  Also, I attempted to format your code, please don't use so much spacing next time.

Comment: I don't get any errors, online cart button does't work http://www.themovieaimless.com/test.php.  I will upload screen shot of desktop

Comment: Odd.  I'm not that familiar with the scripts you're using; can you link them?(I'm not talking about jQuery)  Also, do you have a link to your website?

Comment: Also, define 'doesn't work', please.  What did you expect to happen; what happens instead?

Comment: here is image from desktop http://imgur.com/AjsGwRO. when i click on cart this action should happen http://imgur.com/MviOpHy

Comment: The image doesn't help without context; see my above question about what 'doesn't work' means.

Comment: Clicking on Cart Button should show action example http://imgur.com/MviOpHy

Comment: Then I don't know what you're problem is; perhaps you're looking at a cached page?  I say this because in every browser I have(Firefox, Safari, Chrome), except IE, your code works fine.

Comment: Thank you everyone, I placed lib locally instead calling it and it worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

maybe your server blocked connection to load the jquery library as you are using is loaded from internet

{
script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript">
}

can you open your browser and check the console see if the jquery library is loaded properly?
in chrome, simply right click -> inspect element -> Console tab or f12 -> console tab.

Comment: Thank you everyone, I placed lib locally instead calling it and it worked.